# How to give proper auth for a Google Cloud Function to access the Calendar API in Python

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, google-calendar-api

I have a script that checks a calendar for some events on a private calendar, and I want to have it run in GCF. Right now, I followed the Calendar API quickstart guide, and my authentication method is as follows:

```
# relevant imports
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from httplib2 import Http

# Setup the Calendar API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

Here, token.json and credentials.json are from the configuration file after enabling the Calendar API on my project.

If I copy this directly to a function, I of course hit an error when it tried to load credentials.json, since there are no external files.

Given that my goal is to make this accessible from a GCF url, how can I make this authentication work?

Note: I do have a service account associated with the function, so is there a way I can give that SA access to the private calendar and somehow authenticate with that SA in the python script?

Comment: I know it has been 4 years but I would love an answer to this. It 's still very much an issue in 2022.